# How do i group rows in gridview?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have table like this

```
ID |Company| Product
--------------------
1  |  KP   |  O/D
1  |  KD   |  L/C
```

I want to group by ID and multiple Company and Product separated by comma like this

```
1 |KD,KP  |O/D,L/C
```

Please post the code for example. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

This **problem** is about your **Database** side:

If you are using **Mysql** Use **[Group_Concat](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)**

Try this

```
SELECT ID,Group_Concat(Company),Group_Concat(Product)
FROM tbl
Group By ID
```

<kbd>**[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9322c/1)**</kbd>

If you are using **MSSQL**

Try this

```
  SELECT Distinct T1.ID,
  STUFF(
         (SELECT ',' + T2.Company
          FROM tbl T2
          WHERE T1.ID = T2.ID
          FOR XML PATH (''))
          , 1, 1, '')  AS Company,
  STUFF(
         (SELECT ',' + T3.Product
          FROM tbl T3
          WHERE T1.ID = T3.ID
          FOR XML PATH (''))
          , 1, 1, '')  AS Product
  FROM tbl T1;
```

<kbd>**[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0ccfc/2)**</kbd>

Comment: Thank you so much mr.Vignesh Kumar

Comment: Do you have any idea for convert that code to Linq.

Comment: @user3534404 I don't have idea about it, but you can use http://www.sqltolinq.com/ link to use software to convrt it..

Comment: thanks for advice. I try to use that software but that software doesn't support command "FOR XML PATH"